# Which is correct, "why should people be aware of..." or "why people should be aware of..."?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-inversion, questions

I just want to know which one is correct. I have asked the same question to someone and she said that the latter is more acceptable but the first one's not wrong but can be changed for it to be "better".

Comment: Are you intending to ask a question or make a declaration?  And what is the complete sentence?

Comment: He is asking when to say 'why should people be aware of" and when to say "why people should be aware of". In other words, he's asking when the interrogative pronoun 'why' is followed by a question form, and when it's followed by a sentence form. I taught English to non-native speakers for 25 years, and have learned to decipher a non-native's query. No reason to put the question on hold. Students of English are often unable to express themselves clearly in the language they're learning, as anyone who has tried to learn a second language can relate to.

Answer (score 1):

In a sentence, you would say - I want to explain why people should be aware of the law regarding drinking and driving. In a question, you would say - Why should people be aware of the law regarding drinking and driving? In a question where the word "why" is not at the beginning - Can you explain why people should be aware of the law regarding drinking and driving?